# How to get (year of week number, week number) for a date set

Tags: sql, impala, week-number

I would like to get (year of week number, week number) tuplets for a set of dates.

In Impala SQL, there is function `weekofyear` which gives the correct week number:

```
select year('2018-12-31'), weekofyear('2018-12-31')

year('2018-12-31')|weekofyear('2018-12-31')|
------------------|------------------------|
              2018|                       1|
```

But function `year` does not work if one wants to order (year, week number) tuplets in string format 'yyyyWwk'.

Is there a neat way to get 'yyyyWwk' for each date? Date `2018-12-31` given in the above example would yield result `2019W01`.

This does not work:

```
select concat(cast(year(dt) as STRING),'W',lpad(cast(weekofyear(dt) as string),2,"0")) as wk, dt
  from (
select '2018-11-30' as dt 
union 
select '2018-12-31' as dt
union 
select '2019-01-31' as dt
       ) as t
 order by 1, 2;
```

as it does not order the dates correctly:

```
wk     |dt        |
-------|----------|
2018W01|2018-12-31|
2018W48|2018-11-30|
2019W05|2019-01-31|
```

**How to get a "week-year"=`2019` for the date `2018-12-31`?**

Comment: `dayofyear('2018-12-31')` will return 365, so you could probably devise some logic based on that and `weekofyear()` being 1, to increment the `year()` result by 1. Not pretty but...

Comment: @mazaneicha I was thinking also some complicated solutions. The `date_trunc('week', dt)` approach suggested by @gordon-linoff seems most promising candidate as a beautiful solution.

Comment: Here is better question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012874/convert-date-to-iso-week-date

Comment: Per ISO, first week of a year is the one that has 4 (or more) days in that week. If it is less than 4, it is considered to be the last week of previous year.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just an `order by` issue, then I speculate that  you have some sort of aggregation query.  If so, you can use:

```
order by min(datecol)
```

This will order the overall query correctly.

That said, if you want information by *week*, then use `date_trunc()` instead of extracting the year and week:

```
select date_trunc('week', '2018-12-31')
```

Comment: This `date_trunc` can be used to get all dates of the week to the same year.  But still `weekofyear(date_trunc('week','2018-12-31'))` is 1 and `year(date_trunc('week','2018-12-31'))` is 2018.

Comment: @Heikki . . . True.  But your question is about *ordering* the data, not about getting the right year.  You don't need the year to order the data correctly.

Comment: Sometimes it is difficult to formulate the question accurately in the beginning. Actually that `date_trunc` can be used so solve the question, because the year can be taken from the end of the week: `year(adddate(date_trunc('week','2018-12-31'),6))` yields `2019`.

Comment: @Heikki . . . That may work for 2018/2019, but it won't work for other years where the 53rd week goes into the following year.

Comment: Yes, this is actually more complicated. In the last iteration I have `year(date_trunc('week',dt)) as wkyear` and `weekofyear(date_trunc('week',dt))`. Seems like the year change goes slightly more often to week 1 than to weeks 52 or 53.

Comment: @Heikki . . . I want to emphasize that this question appears to be about *ordering* the results correctly.  If you have a question about the accurate calculate of the year, then ask a *new* question.

Comment: I tried to be accurate, but `year(date_trunc('week',dt))` and `weekofyear(date_trunc('week',dt))` actually messes `2018-12-31` instead.

Comment: New question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012874/convert-date-to-iso-week-date

Answer (score 0):

You can use column aliases in the `order by` clause

```
select year(datecol) as yr, weekofyear(datecol) as wk
  from yourtable
 order by yr, wk
```

as both `year()` and `weekofyear()` functions return `integer` values.

*Aliases are allowed at the top level of the GROUP BY, HAVING, and ORDER BY clauses, e.g. GROUP BY alias* from [the documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.0.3/impala-sql-reference/topics/impala-aliases.html)

Comment: Clarified the question in order to explain why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar to you above and got caught out by the fact that 1 Jan 2021 falls into year 2021 but weekofyear 53!

The fix for you (and me) would be to find the monday in that week (if we're on a sunday, we go forward a day!) and then calculate the weekofyear and year from that. The impala code is which uses dayofweek and days_sub to get to the monday of the week (or if we're already on a monday, stay on it). We do -2 because dayofweek for monday itself is 2.

I originally chose Sunday to go with, but the weekofyear in impala changes on a Monday, so Monday is better

```
with dts as (
    select '2018-11-30' as dt 
    union 
    select '2018-12-31' as dt
    union 
    select '2019-01-01' as dt
    union     
    select '2019-01-31' as dt
    union
    select '2020-12-30' as dt
    union
    select '2020-12-31' as dt
    union
    select '2021-01-01' as dt
    union
    select '2021-01-02' as dt
    union
    select '2021-01-03' as dt
    union
    select '2021-01-04' as dt
    union    
    select '2021-01-09' as dt    
    union
    select '2021-01-10' as dt
    union
    select '2021-01-11' as dt
),
step1 as (
    select
        dt,
        dayofweek(dt) as dayweek,
         dayofweek(dt)-2,
        days_sub(dt, dayofweek(dt)-2) as monOfWeek,
        days_sub(dt, dayofweek(dt)-1) as sunOfWeek
    from dts
)
select 
    dt,
    weekofyear(monOfWeek) as monweeknum,
    year(monofWeek) monyear
from step1 t
order by dt;
```

resulting in:

dt  monweeknum  monyear
2018-11-30  48  2018
2018-12-31  1   2018
2019-01-01  1   2018
2019-01-31  5   2019
2020-12-30  53  2020
2020-12-31  53  2020
2021-01-01  53  2020
2021-01-02  53  2020
2021-01-03  1   2021
2021-01-04  1   2021
2021-01-09  1   2021
2021-01-10  2   2021
2021-01-11  2   2021

Bit more information for why this craziness happens is in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

and an interactive calculator in
https://www.timeanddate.com/date/weeknumber.html

Answer (score 0):

Late to the question but was looking at the problem and by using **string format** we can go directly to ISO-weeks (iw), also using ISO-year (iyyy).

Example query:

```
select cast(cast('20210124' as date format 'YYYYMMDD') as string format 'iyyyiW')
```

Returns

```
202103
```

Answer (score 0):

select to_date(date_sub(to_date(cast('2021-11-23' as timestamp ) ),(dayofweek(cast('2021-11-23' as timestamp))-2))) week_start_date

Note :- week start on Monday then - 2 in the above formula